# Azure Function err: microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http

Tags: azure, function

I just had the same 'TestTrigger' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"-error in a v4 function running .Net 6.0.

error  :
"System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYHCw.png)

Answer (score 4):

It think this issue is misleading.

I changed **TargetFramework** from **netcoreapp3.1** to **net6.0** and this issue started to appearing.

I was looking for solutions in the web, without any success. In the end I created new Azure Function and copy code step by step.

It occurred that for my case I needed to

- remove dependencies
- add **_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput** property

In the screenshot below please focus on **Microsoft.Extension** part.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was a real head-scratcher and the _FunctionsSkipCleanOutput property worked for me.